# Select rows from table that have duplicate field, but prioritize group by

Tags: mysql, database

table with `columns id, order_number, location`
data looks like

```
[1, 123, 'texas']
[2, 123, 'ny']
[3, 456, 'texas']
[4, 456, 'ny']
[5, 678, 'hawaii']
```

I want to select the `id`'s of records from `ny` that have the same `order_number` as in `texas`

Comment: I have this, but the id's are only from texas and i want the duplicate id from ny. `select id from a where location in ('texas','ny')
GROUP BY order_number HAVING COUNT(order_number) > 1;`

Comment: Your query has a problem, because you're grouping by `order_number` but then selecting `id`, a non aggregate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use an `EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT id
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE location = 'ny' AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                                  WHERE t1.order_number = t2.order_number AND
                                        t2.location = 'texas');
```

**Edit:** If you want to use an aggregation approach, that's possible too:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN location = 'ny' THEN id END) AS id
FROM yourTable
WHERE location IN ('ny', 'texas')
GROUP BY order_number
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT location) = 2;
```

### Demo

Here, we can aggregate by `order_number`, and then pivot out the `id` values for New York.